# Difference between Map[f[#] + g[#] &, {a, b, c}] and Map[f[x]+g[x]&, {a, b, c}]

Tags: syntax, symbolic

```
  Map[f[#] + g[#] &, {a, b, c}] vs Map[f[x]+g[x]&, {a, b, c}]
```

My question is: why is the output different?

```
Map[f[#] + g[#] &, {a, b, c}]

(* {f[a] + g[a], f[b] + g[b], f[c] + g[c]} *)
```

and

```
Map[f[x] + g[x] &, {a, b, c}]

(* {f[x] + g[x], f[x] + g[x], f[x] + g[x]} *)
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation to find out what is the role of the slot (#).

Comment: Maybe Map[  Function[x, f[x]+g[x]],  {a,b,c} ]  is more readable. Check out the documentation for Function.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask the question: What are the values of `#` and of `x` ?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to compare something like the following? `myfn[x_] := f[x] + g[x]; 
myfn /@ {a, b, c} == (f@# + g@# & /@ {a, b, c})` (=> True)

Comment: To make the point perhaps more dramatically, what would you expect `Map[f[5] + g[5] &, {a, b, c}]` to give? Your second construction, with `x` instead of `5`, is the same kind of situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Map` function lets you apply a function to every element of a list. So:

```
Map[Sin, {0, Pi/2, Pi}]
```

applies `Sin` to each of the three values in the list which occupies the second place in the `Map` function call. The result is a list of numbers:

> {0, 1, 0}

If you define your own functions, you can use them in a similar way:

```
double[x_] := x + x;

Map[double, {0, Pi/2, Pi}]
```

> {0, π, 2 π}

You can use `#` or `Slot`, together with the ampersand (&), to refer to the arguments or parameters of a function, like this:

```
Map[Sin[#] + Cos[#] &, {0, Pi/2, Pi}]
```

> {1, 1, -1}

When *Mathematica* doesn't understand what you typed, it returns it to you unchanged:

```
Map[f [x] g[x] &, {0, Pi/2, Pi}]
```

> {f[x] g[x], f[x] g[x], f[x] g[x]}

The syntax highlighter in the notebook should indicate which parts of your code don't mean anything to *Mathematica*. On my machine, it shows in blue:

[image: screen grab]